# Timestamp for each cell in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` chat, and I want to display the time for each message.

[image]

Here is the `dequeueReusable` cell function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCollectionVIewCell
    let message = messagesArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.configure(with: message)



    return cell

}
```

And here is the configure function inside my `collectionViewCell` file
, Messages: is of type `NSManagedOBject`(core data), and it has 3 properties: `usserMessage`, `isFromApi`, and `timeDate`.

```
func configure(with message:Messages)
{
    messageOutlet.text = message.userMessage
    viewForMessages.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray


    let currentDateTime = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    formatter.dateStyle = .none


    timeLabel.text = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)


    if message.isFromApi == true
    {
        viewForMessages.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        trailingConstraint.constant = 40
        leadingConstraint.constant = 10
    }
    else
    {
        viewForMessages.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.5898008943, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        trailingConstraint.constant = 10
        leadingConstraint.constant = 40
    }
}
```

At the moment it shows me correctly the time for first Message, but when I add another message at another minute, it changes also the time for the first message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching the date on runtime, so for each cell it will only show the current time, say 9:58 in your case. To avoid this you need to store the time in your Messages model.

Try following for this:

> Add time property in your model,  `Messages.swift`

```
var timeString: String?
```

> In `collectionViewCell.swift`, Update your `configure()` function as following:

```
func configure(with message: Messages) {
    messageOutlet.text = message.userMessage
    viewForMessages.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    // Check whether time is already present in model or you need to set it as current time
    if let time = message.timeString {
        // time is already present in model
        timeLabel.text = time

    } else {
        // time is not present in model, you need to set it with current time
        let currentDateTime = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        formatter.dateStyle = .none

        let formattedTime = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
        message.timeString = formattedTime // Save the time in model, for future use
        timeLabel.text = formattedTime
    }

    if message.isFromApi == true {
        viewForMessages.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        trailingConstraint.constant = 40
        leadingConstraint.constant = 10
    } else {
        viewForMessages.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.5898008943, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        trailingConstraint.constant = 10
        leadingConstraint.constant = 40
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it makes sense, only one problem, I cannot use a string on my message, because my message is of type CoreData, I have added a new property in my CoreData  called timeData that is of Type Date, should I change it to be of type String?

Comment: @DanielArdeleanu, Not necessarily, you can go with the `Date` type as well

Comment: @DanielArdeleanu, just a concern that if you will take a property with `Date` type then you need to create `formatter` and call `formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)` while loading cell. But if you will save timeString in string format same as you are saving `userMessage` then you can directly access as shown in answer.

Answer (score 2):

`let currentDateTime = Date()` is being called each time the cell is being rendered.

You need to store the time in the message object when it's created and read the value for it each time you are calling your `configure` method. something like :

```
let messageDate = message.messageDate
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .short
formatter.dateStyle = .none


timeLabel.text = formatter.string(from: messageDate)
```